# Select2 input-group fixed width

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

input group select 2 element is disrespecting parent element width by going wider what it should !

*selecting a normal option looks fine*

[image: selecting a normal option looks fine]
*when i select a longer option it will look like this*

[image: when i select a longer option it will look like this]
how can i have a fixed width for the "Select 2"  container even if long text chosen?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right,you want the second selector to be shorter than the first one

```
<select name="select2" style="width:100px; display:block;">
```

Comment: actually i would like to get away from setting fixed width for the element since this may affect the visual from screen to another;

Comment: @SuhaybKharabsheh you can set % instead of px